# The called method `...' is defined here

Tags: ruby

Ruby 2.7 was just released and it comes with these new warnings for *"Separation of positional and keyword arguments"* (see their [Release Post](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/)).
I was playing around with it and discovered that there's another warning, which I don't understand.

Example:

```rb
def multiply(x:, y:)
  x * y
end

args = { x: 2, y: 3 }

multiply(args)

# ./warning.rb:7: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
# ./warning.rb:1: warning: The called method `multiply' is defined here
```

I think the first warning about the deprecation is clear, but the second warning `` The called method `multiply' is defined here `` is confusing to me.

What does the second warning mean? Is it related to the first warning?

Both warnings disappear when adding `**` to the call (`multiply(**args)`).

Comment: Anyone know how to suppress these warnings? I have deprecations warnings writing to the log file, but it doesn't affect these ones. Running specs is a nightmare in ruby 2.7.0

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> What does the second warning mean? Is it related to the first warning?

There is a single warning with a text split into two lines. It literally says: *`args` should be converted to `**args`, here is the call that produced this warning, here is its definition for your convenience*.

Comment: Nice, thank you! May be it's just me, but this is quite confusing...

Comment: @lxxxvi It's not just you. I've come here for exactly the same thing - if it's one error message, I feel like it should be one error message.

Comment: I'm really confused, I'm seeing this warning and there is nothing above it for i18n.rb, this is a single line warning, the line above relates to active support. What am I supposed to do about this warning? < /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/i18n-1.8.2/lib/i18n.rb:195: warning: The called method `t' is defined here

Comment: @Hackeron I just had a similar/same problem. The warning said, that the method is defined in i18n gem. However, the line just above that one is the location that caused the warning, and it does not have to be from same gem! In my case it was a `I18n.t`-call in the devise gem (`devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:110`). I also found that the "misunderstood" warning is described in i18n's file [lib/i18n.rb:195](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/438690d090180da1b606bf17662af35f20b054a1/lib/i18n.rb#L195) just above line 195.